# scaling of stat_density levels

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have the following data, called `grid`:

```
    conc    viscos     temp process filtration    psize speed
1     23 148.73609 23.78377       3          1 55.64441     2
1.1   23 128.28465 23.19413       3          1 58.68403     2
1.2   23 154.57065 27.37000       3          1 54.77725     2
1.3   23 154.68350 25.75547       3          1 54.76047     2
1.4   23 123.89097 27.00756       3          1 59.33705     2
1.5   23 174.87409 29.25369       3          1 51.75963     2
1.6   23 113.20778 23.67193       3          1 60.92485     2
1.7   23  99.76474 27.88921       3          1 62.92283     2
1.8   23 139.65546 28.21860       3          1 56.99403     2
1.9   23 108.02552 23.45404       3          1 61.69506     2

structure(list(conc = c(23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23), 
viscos = c(148.736087893612, 128.284646104976, 154.570647098922, 54.68349762674, 123.890966907047, 174.874091619764, 113.207780061696, 99.7647376022436, 139.655456470316, 108.025515976116), 
temp = c(23.7837716944317, 23.1941282546014, 27.3700015971809, 25.7554684507881, 27.0075589349605, 29.2536879749291, 23.6719254390264, 27.8892069496691, 28.21860386208, 23.4540375461545), 
process = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), 
.Label = c("1", "2", "3"), 
class = "factor"), 
filtration = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L), 
.Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), 
psize = c(55.6444133654302, 
58.6840302266575, 54.7772459196543, 54.7604733922843, 59.3370453788836, 
51.7596253066746, 60.9248451634842, 62.9228313665229, 56.9940316793908, 
61.6950645669207), 
speed = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
.Label = c("1", "2", "3"), class = "factor")), 
.Names = c("conc", "viscos", "temp", "process", "filtration", "psize", "speed"), row.names = c("1", "1.1", "1.2", "1.3", "1.4", "1.5", "1.6", "1.7", "1.8", "1.9"), 
class = "data.frame")
```

I make a contour plot of this data via the following command:

```
  c <- ggplot(grid, aes(x = temp, y = viscos, z = psize)) +
  stat_density_2d(aes(color=..level..), show.legend = TRUE) +
  scale_color_gradient(name = "psize", low = "#40FF00", high = "#FF0000") +
  ggtitle(title) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  geom_dl(aes(label=..level..), method = list("bottom.pieces", cex=0.5), stat = "density_2d")
```

[image: contour plot]

It is the plot I want, however, the z value is rescaled to density values. I want to change this and put the 'real' z values in the plot (both in directlabels and the legend). So I want the z values on the scale of the variable psize. Is there any way to do this?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please paste output of `dput(grid)` into your question to make your data easily accessible.

Comment: I pasted the output to my post!

Comment: Use `geom_contour`? Also note that the z value is not being used in your current plot at all, I think.

Comment: Are you trying to estimate and plot the joint probability distribution of `temp` and `viscos`, or are you trying to approximate and plot the function `psize = f(temp, viscos)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a misunderstanding of what `stat_density_2d(aes(color=..level..), show.legend = TRUE)` plots, it is not the `psize` value but the density distribution of points in the x,y coordinates.

As you are not plotting in 3D, `aes(z = psize)` has no meaning in the current plot -- as proof, you can remove it and get the exact same plot. Let us add `geom_point` to show what `stat_density_2d` is showing, which is where the points are concentrated:

```
library(directlabels)

ggplot(grid, aes(x = temp, y = viscos)) +
  geom_point() +
  stat_density_2d(aes(color=..level..), show.legend = TRUE) +
  scale_color_gradient(name = "psize", low = "#40FF00", high = "#FF0000") +
  ggtitle(title) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  geom_dl(aes(label=..level..), method = list("bottom.pieces", cex=0.5), stat = "density_2d")
```

What you can do is add `psize` as `aes(fill=psize)` to `geom_point` which will show the the gradient levels of `psize` and use `geom_text` or `geom_text_repel` from the `ggrepel` package to annotate the point values.

```
library(ggrepel)

ggplot(grid, aes(x = temp, y = viscos)) +
  geom_point(aes(fill = psize), shape=21, size=3) +
  geom_text_repel(aes(label = round(psize, digits=2)), size=3) + 
  scale_fill_gradient(name = "psize", low = "#40FF00", high = "#FF0000") +
  stat_density_2d(aes(colour=..level..), show.legend = TRUE) +
  geom_dl(aes(label=..level..), method = list("bottom.pieces", cex=0.5), stat = "density_2d") +
  scale_colour_gradient(low = "dark blue", high = "sky blue")
```

I use two gradient scales, `colour` gradient for `stat_density_2d(..level..)`, and `fill` gradient for `aes(fill=psize)`. As you can see, you can have high `psize` value at low density of points (and vice versa).

[image]

Comment: You are right, I was misunderstanding the function... Still learning. This seems like a fair solution, thank you!